# research on the structure/properties of permutation matrix/table with $(i,j)th$ entry as $\pi_j\circ \pi_i^{-1}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Is there any research on the structure/properties of permutation matrix/table with $(i,j)th$ entry as $\pi_j\circ \pi_i^{-1}$, where $\{\pi_1,\pi_2,...,\pi_{k!}\}=S_k$?

I know if we apply the function of taking the number of inversions onto above table entry-wisely to get a matrix, then the so-defined matrix is actually a conditionally positive semidefinite where it is refined to subspace $\{x|e^Tx=0\}$. This result is by Bapat and Raghavan in "Nonnegative Matrices and Applications".

But right now I am working on taking the longest increasing subsequence of that table and it turns out to be hard so that I am trying to dig out as many properties as I can.

Is there any advanced technique such as representation theory can be used here? Any general big-idea talk or specific advice are welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: How big are these matrices supposed to be? It looks to me like a $k! \times k!$ table of $k \times k$ matrices. Is that what you intend?

Comment: it's not clear what kind of order on permutations you are talking about, and, indeed, what the entries of these tables are.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2460. They study a-non-inversions on exactly that matrix; these are $w_{i_1} < \ldots < w_{i_a}$ for a permutation $w \in \mathcal{S}_n$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, if you prefer using permutation matrices to represent permutations.

Comment: For now, I am using increasing order if you consider the dictionary as $\[n\]$. @DimaPasechnik

Comment: Thanks for the link. That paper is very much related to my problem and it introduces me something about algebraic statistics on the topic of data ranking in which many functions of permutations have been applied to the table I mentioned. @ChristianStump